# Token Authentication stopped working after migration from ASP.NET Core 1 to ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I followed this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) to migrate my website from ASP.NET Core 1 to ASP.NET Core 2.

However after doing the ASP Identity changes my authentication stopped working.

My services look like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddResponseCaching();

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["SecretKey"];
    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "arnvanhoutte",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "User",
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        });

    services.AddWebSocketManager();

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<Seed>();
}
```

And I have `app.UseAuthentication();` at the bottom of my Configure method.

However when I check `var isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;` this in a controller it always says false. It worked before though so I don't understand why this stopped working.

Comment: Did you run migrations on you DB again?

Comment: I tried that now but I keep getting this error: `Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.`

Comment: Interesting, That probably why your context isn't working, maybe you're generating an Old version of ApplicationDbContext, isn't there a new one associated with .Net-Core-2.0 I still haven't upgraded because IdentityServer4 needs to upgrade

Comment: I managed to do my migrations now after upgrading to a parameterless constructor. But my claims still aren't working

Comment: is it redirects to 404 or throwing 401 for authentication!

Comment: It doesn't redirect. It just says my claims are empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue during the migration

For me the login worked without any issue,but subsequent request failed with a redirect to the login page instead of throwing a 401(which caused a 404 as its 
 a web api i didn't had any login page!).

**Adding the defaultauthenticationscheme and DefaultChallengeScheme to the addauthentication did the trick for me.**

Changing the addauthentication as follows to make the jwt authentication work!

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });
```