# Jwt not working after converting Asp.Net Core 1 to Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, rsa, hmac

There is a sample code for **Jwt-Rsa-Hmac authentication** on [this](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/07/24/jwt-rsa-hmac-asp-net-core/) web site with [this](https://github.com/spetz/jwt-hmac-rsa-aspnet-core-sample) repo.
I have been trying to convert it from Asp.Net Core 1 to Asp.Net Core 2.
I created a new Asp.Net Cor 2.1 project and after searching the changes it needed, I came up with [this](https://github.com/a-molaei/RSA_Core2) code.
It does create the token, but when using the token I always get `401` (unauthorized).
It's been a few days and no success...
I will be grateful if anyone could help me with this.
This is my startup class:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("jwt"));
            var x = services.AddSingleton<IJwtHandler, JwtHandler>();

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var jwtHandler = sp.GetService<IJwtHandler>();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = jwtHandler.Parameters;
            });
            services.AddMvc();

        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

And the rest of the sample code is in [this](https://github.com/a-molaei/RSA_Core2) repo.

Links I have already studies:
[Token Authentication stopped working after migration from ASP.NET Core 1 to ASP.NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824690/token-authentication-stopped-working-after-migration-from-asp-net-core-1-to-asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your sample repository is, that you are creating new `JwtBearerOptions` [here](https://github.com/a-molaei/RSA_Core2/blob/4f8321a7e890a1c1f29c4258b0d4ef5ceb0a3db7/RSA_Core2/Startup.cs#L63).

I changed it to this and it works just fine

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{

    o.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = jwtHandler.Parameters;
    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
        {
            c.NoResult();

            c.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            return c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString());
        }

    };
});
```

I have sent you a [pull-request](https://github.com/a-molaei/RSA_Core2/pull/1).

Answer (score 0):

I used this setting in .netcore2.1 and work for me:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["BearerTokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["BearerTokens:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["BearerTokens:Key"])),

                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };

            });
```